# How to use a single SQL DB Connection string?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am developing an ASP .NET application on my PC and deploying it on a host.

The application uses a Microsoft SQL DB, I have two databases one local and one on a server.

How should the application be configured so it could connect to both DBs without any code changes? (the 2 databases have identical names and structure)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the connection string in web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Name" connectionString="..." />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then in your code:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: I used to hate them when switching between development and production. But .NET 4's .config transformations are pretty darn cool!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store all of them in one config file, you can also do some indirection like this:

```
string name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB"]
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;

<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="DB" name="Prod" />
 </appSettings>    
 <connectionStrings>        
   <add name="Prod" connectionString="..." />    
   <add name="Test" connectionString="..." />    
   <add name="Dev" connectionString="..." />    
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

It comes down to who can edit config in produciton and how you're allowed to deploy software.  Sometimes this is a viable solution with the actual option to use being specified somewhere else altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the web.config is that you have to change it when you deploy.

I have a post arguing for machine.config [here](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2009/02/24/Where-to-put-the-connection-string.aspx).

For places where you can't edit the machine.config I show a way to have it in a config file that is not under your web site's directory [here.](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2009/06/18/Another-Place-to-Put-the-Connection-String.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

and a [nice website](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) which specifies the connection string for most DBs